# MongoDB / Mongoose Schema structuring for nested subdocuments

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to create a schema where I can add the same item type as a child to itself.

For instance, a page can be a sub-page with the same properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId` and make a reference to the same schema.

In your case, it might be like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const PageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },

  subPage: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Page'
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Page', PageSchema)
```

By the way, don't forget to register your schema with the same name as you use in the reference. In the above example, it is registered as `Page`.